# How to access Array value from outside scope with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Okay so I know this is a really stupid question. I looked everywhere before making this thread and I am just completely unable to figure it out. This is the code I had. My issue is that between passing the value from getJSON to the angular controller, my array has lost its values. What is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do here?

```
function getJSON(json) {
    data = [];
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        data.push(value);
    });
    console.log(data); // Accurately logs array data
    return data;
}
function passValue() {
    return getJSON();
}
app.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    x = passValue()
    $scope.title = x[0]; // Throws error
    console.log(x); // Only returns an empty array
}
```

And this I have in a script on my html file. It works 100%.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("{{ url_for('static', filename='movies.json') }}?id={{ movie_id }}", function(json) {
         getJSON(json);
});
```

For example, this works.

```
function getJSON(json) {
    data = [];
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        data.push(value);
    });
    console.log(data) // Acurrately logs array data
    document.getElementById('exampleDiv').innerHTML = data[0] // Accurately appends array data (0 being title)
}
```

Comment: This code looks *simplified*, is it? I suspect there are a few crucial lines missing, such as a `fetch` or something similar

Comment: My getJSON method is not simplified. It works in acquiring my json data. It is a called method from another script. I can use it to put the json value into html normally, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it with HTML. I'll put that other code into my main post.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I'm surprised that, if `x` is an empty array, that `$scope.title = x[0];` throws an error, since that *should* just assign `undefined` to `$scope.title`. Probably an angular thing I'm unfamiliar with

Comment: Yeah I'm quite unfamiliar with angular too, I'm sure there's a simple solution to this issue I just can't come up with one. I'm probably just being dumb honestly!

Comment: You are calling `getJSON()` without an argument in `passValue` function. That does not seem correct as the getJSON function definition expects one.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I was confused because I wasn't sure how to pass that same variable properly. I ended up changing my code to a version I think works better, if you check my answer.

Comment: I'm curious, what exactly is the error that gets thrown in your original code on the line `$scope.title = x[0];`? If the passed value is `undefined`, the error *should* be thrown at the `$.each` line instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that fixes my problem. If anyone has a similar issue, I hope this helps you as well.

```
function getJSON(json) {
    data = [];
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        data.push(value);
    });
    console.log(data)
    update(data)
}

function update(data) {
    var $scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('#movie')).scope()
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.title = data[0];
    });
}

app.controller('MovieController', function($scope) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window` to store and access data between angular and any component. Angular has a wrapper called `$window` to access it too.

In javascript:

```
function foo(value){
    window.data = value;
}
```

In angular:

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

  $scope.getData= function() {
    //using $window
    alert($window.data);
    //Or 
    alert(window.data);
  };
}]);
```